# How to build a robot that can stop at a certain point using an altimeter

Tags: arduino-uno

I am thinking about creating a robot that climbs vertically and stops at a certain point. I thought about using an altimiter in order to measure the distance, however, I dont know how to create a code for it. Where would you start with it, can it be done with MATLAB?

Thanks for everything :)

Comment: You can use an barometer/air pressure sensor for height, or an acceleromater for relative (height) changes. I don't see where MATLAB comes in.

Comment: you are asking the wrong question .... your question should be `how do i measure altitude?`

Comment: Before you consider code, you'll need a way to measure altitude changes. Barometric altimetry (air-pressure based) is probably too crude for the scale of robot you're likely interested in. The change in atmospheric pressure with altitude is (very) appx 1 in-hg/1000ft near sea-level or ~1/2 psi/1000ft. If you want 1 foot altitude precision, you'd need .5/1000 or a pressure measurement good to within 0.0005 psi. A sneeze in the same room could crash your robot! :) ...

Comment: ... Other means of measurement are likely to be more successful with existing and affordable technologies. If you can work with elevation instead of altitude (height above a surface, like a floor), radar, sonar, or even a sounding line (a fishing line with a weight you drop to the floor and measure how much line you let out) are going to be much easier. You'll need to make these kinds of design decisions before you'll be ready to write code.

Answer (score 2):

have fun playing with the Arduino and some sensors! It is a great platform to learn. For your task, look into the Bosch sensor modules [BME280](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/BST-BME280_DS001-10.pdf) (pressure with temperature and humidity) or [BMP280](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/BST-BMP280-DS001-11.pdf) (just pressure). You can expect maybe +-1 meter of accuracy. Or check the precision version [BME388](https://datasheet.octopart.com/BMP388-Bosch-Tools-datasheet-103686868.pdf) that could give you +-50cm. Go to the [adafruit shop](https://www.adafruit.com/category/114) and try a few of the breakout boards. They provide great library and documentation support.

In order to get absolute altitudes, you need to factor in ambient air pressure. A good source for that are [METAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/METAR) reports issued for aircraft. There are many online sources where you can get the so called *altimeter setting* for an airport close to you. Airplane altimeters actually just show the altitude above a standard pressure plane, so you need to compensate for whatever pressure the current weather gives you.

For higher precision, you pretty soon have to integrate barometric pressure, GPS altitude, and maybe other sensors, with some serious math. This is where MATLAB fits in.